# How to unpack list of lists with unknown number of elements into unique variables?

Tags: python

I recently created a program that will give me a list of lists:

```
myList = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

However, I do not know how many lists this list will contain, but I do want to unpack it into unique variables that I can manipulate later (not a dictionary):

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]
list3 = [5,6]
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time, but I can't. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: The real question is why would you want to do that? What's wrong with using directly `myList[1]`?

Comment: @Julien &John You mean "what is the X problem" in this question, as it is a typical example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This is really not a good idea. Sure, you can use `globals()`, but then you need to keep using `globals()` to access your new variables. So you might as well just create your own `list` or `dict` to hold your objects. Using a `list` lets you access them by an index number. A `dict` gives you more options: you can give each object a name if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't need to unpack them at all: The individual lists can be referenced as unique variables as they are now!

Instead of trying to reference the variables as `list1` with new names, use their existing names:

```
myList = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
print (myList[0]) # Prints out the list [1,2]
print (myList[1]) #Prints out the list [3,4]
print (myList[2]) #Prints out the list [5,6]
```

There are advantages to this format, take for example this made up list:

```
myListOfUnexpectedSize = [[1,3],[5,7],...more lists...,[15,17]]
print(len(myListOfUnexpectedSize)) #Prints out the number of lists you have
for lis in myListOfUnexpectedSize: #This loop will print out all the lists one by one
    print(lis) 
print(myListOfUnexpectedSize[-1]) #Prints out the last list in the big list
```

So by using the size of the larger list, you can figure out how many lists you have inside and work with them.

Comment: Ajax's answer actually answers the question, whereas I just sidestep the question and show a different solution to the issue... people who are upvoting me should upvote that person as well.

Comment: Sure, Ajax's answer does what the OP asked for, but really the OP shouldn't be doing that. They should be using a list, like your answer shows, or perhaps a dict. Manhandling `globals()` is rarely a good idea. And once you've created "variable variables" via `globals()` you have to keep using it to access those variables.

Answer (score 2):

What you may want is a collection, such as lists to hold each list, and then you can reference it by index. Alternatively, you could consider a dictionary and a bit of list comprehension as follows if you really want to reference it by a specific name

```
listDict = {"list" + str(key+1) : value for (key, value) in enumerate(myList)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you may have more than three sublists, you can try this:

```
myList = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
list1, list2, list3, *rest = myList
print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)
```

the rest will hold the remaining sublists, and the list1, list2, list3 are the ones you want.